# Error trying to use C# ftpwebrequest to ftp xml file to Zebra printer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I've used ZebraDesigner for xml ver2.0 to create some label templates for a Zebra 170PAX4 printer.  I've successfully exported the zpl to the Zebra and I can edit and send the xml file to the Zebra using ftp in a Windows command prompt like this:`c:\ftp 10.161.41.212
Connected to 10.161.41.212.
220 ZBR-46688 Version 1.01.7 ready.
User (10.161.41.212:(none)):
230 User logged in.
ftp> put c:SPver1_1.xml
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for SPver1_1.xml.
226 Transfer complete.
ftp: 324 bytes sent in 0.00Seconds 324000.00Kbytes/sec`

Now, I'm trying to used MS VS2010 and C# to do this automatically from a WinForms application.  But for some reason no what I'm seem to try using the FtpWebRequest class, I also receive a error

> The remote server returned an error:  (502) Command not implemented.

From what I understand, the ftp method UploadFile is the same as STOR which is the same as the alias put.  The code I'm using is shown below:

```
public bool PutXmlFile(CZebraPrinter printer, CDeviceContainer devices)
    {
        bool OK = true;
        CDevice currDevice = new CDevice();
        currDevice = devices.GetDevice(this.m_devName);
        string ftpHost = "ftp://" + printer.m_IPAddress + "/";
        string ftpPath = "E:";
        Uri printerUri = new Uri(ftpHost + ftpPath);

        try
        {
            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(printerUri);
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = false;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
            ftpRequest.Timeout = 5000;  //milliseconds

            // The Zebra printer uses anonymous login
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(currDevice.m_defaultDataFile);
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();

            Stream requestStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            //Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);
            //Check response
            response.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errMessage = string.Format("An error occured trying to ftp the device xml file to the Zebra printer.  \n\nReason:\n{0}", ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(errMessage, m_mfgInfoErr, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return !OK;
        }
        return OK;
    }
```

Does anyone see what I may be doing wrong.  Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thanks.

I ran the TRACE, here is the output:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpWebRequest#14993092::.ctor(ftp://10.161.41.212/E:)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4780] Exiting WebRequest::Create()     -> FtpWebRequest#14993092
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4780] FtpWebRequest#14993092::GetRequestStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpWebRequest#14993092::GetRequestStream(Method=STOR.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] Associating FtpWebRequest#14993092 with FtpControlStream#720107
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Received response [220 ZBR-46688 Version 1.01.7 ready.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Sending command [USER anonymous]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Received response [230 User logged in.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Sending command [OPTS utf8 on]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Received response [502 Command 'OPTS' not implemented.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Sending command [PWD]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Received response [502 Command 'PWD' not implemented.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpWebRequest#14993092::(Releasing FTP connection#720107.)
System.Net Error: 0 : [4780] Exception in the FtpWebRequest#14993092::GetRequestStream - The remote server returned an error: (502) Command not implemented.
```

So it looks like **OPTS** and **PWD** are the problem.  Is there any way to control what is sent by FtpWebRequest or do I need a 3rd party library?

Answer (score 1):

UploadFile uses STOR command, but before this command is sent, .NET sometimes send other commands such as "OPTS utf8 on" or "TYPE I", etc. If you create configuration file for your application with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="console" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\logfile.txt" />
    </sharedListeners>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net" switchName="sourceSwitch">
        <listeners>
          <add name="console" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="sourceSwitch" value="Verbose"/>
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

all commands and responses will be logged in file, so you can look, which one causes the problem.

**UPDATE:**
So the problem is, that before STOR command is issued, FTP client sends OPTS and PWD commands, which your printer doesn't understand, probably because it is very lightweight FTP server.  Unfortunately I don't know how to prevent these commands to be send. I have only 2 workarounds on my mind:

- find some third-party FTP library, that doesn't send those problematic commands.
- since uploading files from command line works, create file (commands.txt) with appropriate 'put' command and then start FTP transfer from your program like this:

`Process.Start("ftp", "-A -s:commands.txt " + printer.m_IPAddress);`

Comment: OK, I ran the TRACE as you suggested and this is what was logged:

Comment: What was logged? I don't see anything.

Comment: Here was the output:  System.Net Verbose: 0 : [4780] FtpWebRequest#14993092::GetRequestStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpWebRequest#14993092::GetRequestStream(Method=STOR.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] Associating FtpWebRequest#14993092 with FtpControlStream#720107System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Received response [220 ZBR-46688 Version 1.01.7 ready.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Sending command [USER anonymous]
System.Net Information: 0 : [4780] FtpControlStream#720107 - Received response [230 User logged in.]

Comment: Your log is probably too long to be posted in comment. Just find error code 502 and look on previous row what command caused this error (it will be somewhere at the end of log file).

Comment: Nuf, I edited the my original question in order to post the TRACE.

Comment: I took the route of using a 3rd party FTP library, specifically, the one written by **Dan Glass** and **Jaimon Mathew**, et al had done, titled **"FTP client library for C#"**.  This worked out very well for my light weight Zebra printer FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is over a year old but someone else might find this useful. 
If your goal is to send ZPL Code or XML files to your printer you are not bound to the ftp protocol. I'm sending my code via TCP/IP socket. Here is what I use:

```
public void SendCode(string ipAddress, string zplCode)
    {
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientSocket.NoDelay = true;

        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ipAdress);
        IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 9100);
        clientSocket.Connect(ipep);

        byte[] stringBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(zplCode);

        clientSocket.Send(stringBytes);
        clientSocket.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ftpRequest` (FtpWebRequest) created, we have an attribute EnableSsl. If SSL is disabled in the FTP site, then this flag needs to be set as false, else this flag needs to be set as true.

```
ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;
```

This has to be done before opening the `StreamReader`.